# Can't reach internal address from inside a CoreOs Vagrant box

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, coreos

I'm running CoreOS inside a Vagrant box. I'm using the [stock configuration described by CoreOS](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-vagrant.html).

I can successfully ping an external address like Google. Unfortunately I can't reach any address that' inside my companies network.

Pinging an internal address from my Windows host works fine. My colleague has also got no problems calling internal addresses from inside the Vagrant box.

When calling `ifconfig` I have two entries listed that I suspect to be the cause (since my colleague doesn't have those two):

```
flannel0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu XXX
veth071c08e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu XXX
```

Do you know what they are and how I can remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the `flannel` interface and service as well as the `fleet` service from Vagrant's `user-data` file and now I can reach internal addresses as well.